# Why is my intellisense not working in VS Code for CodeceptJS using playwright?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, codeceptjs

I am trying to create a practice environment for CodeceptJS using TS and Playwright, but for some reason VSCodes intellisense refuses to show any suggestions. I can manually type the code and that is fine and works but I would like to get the intellisense working.

I have followed the quickstart guide on the CodeceptJS website to the letter with the following steps:

1. Open directory and execute command `npx create-codeceptjs .` this does an `npm init` and then installs all of the required packages for Codecept and playwright before finally doing an `npx codeceptjs init` which creates the boilerplate TS project.
2. In this project I have the following files:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "lib": ["es2018", "DOM"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "types": ["codeceptjs", "node"],
    "declaration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

steps.d.ts

```
/// <reference types='codeceptjs' />
type steps_file = typeof import('./steps_file');

declare namespace CodeceptJS {
  interface SupportObject { I: I, current: any }
  interface Methods extends Playwright {}
  interface I extends ReturnType<steps_file> {}
  namespace Translation {
    interface Actions {}
  }
}
```

steps_files.ts

```
// in this file you can append custom step methods to 'I' object

module.exports = function() {
  return actor({

    // Define custom steps here, use 'this' to access default methods of I.
    // It is recommended to place a general 'login' function here.
    
  });
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "codeceptjs-tests",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "codeceptjs": "codeceptjs run --steps",
        "codeceptjs:headless": "HEADLESS=true codeceptjs run --steps",
        "codeceptjs:ui": "codecept-ui --app",
        "codeceptjs:demo": "codeceptjs run --steps -c node_modules/@codeceptjs/examples",
        "codeceptjs:demo:headless": "HEADLESS=true codeceptjs run --steps -c node_modules/@codeceptjs/examples",
        "codeceptjs:demo:ui": "codecept-ui --app  -c node_modules/@codeceptjs/examples"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@codeceptjs/configure": "^0.10.0",
        "@codeceptjs/examples": "^1.2.1",
        "@codeceptjs/ui": "^0.5.0",
        "@types/node": "^20.0.0",
        "codeceptjs": "^3.4.1",
        "playwright": "^1.33.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.4"
    }
}
```

login_test.ts

```
Feature('login');

Scenario('test something',  ({ I }) => {

});
```

codecept.conf.ts

```
import { setHeadlessWhen, setCommonPlugins } from '@codeceptjs/configure';
// turn on headless mode when running with HEADLESS=true environment variable
// export HEADLESS=true && npx codeceptjs run
setHeadlessWhen(process.env.HEADLESS);

// enable all common plugins https://github.com/codeceptjs/configure#setcommonplugins
setCommonPlugins();

export const config: CodeceptJS.MainConfig = {
  tests: './*_test.ts',
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
    Playwright: {
      url: 'https://www.saucedemo.com',
      show: true,
      browser: 'chromium'
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file'
  },
  name: 'CodeceptJS'
}
```

With all of this as the standard files that you get from the installation when attempting to call a standard method from Playwright `amOnPage();` from the `I` object of codeceptjs in my `login_test.ts` file, I get no intellisense to show the possible methods. I have looked all over google and cannot find a reason for this to be happening, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This post has an answer that solved it for me.

Replace: `interface I extends ReturnType<steps_file> {}`

With: `interface I extends ReturnType<steps_file>, WithTranslation<Methods> {}`

[Intellisense not working for Playwright, REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74849869/intellisense-not-working-for-playwright-rest)