# VSCode unable to use intellisense with custom steps for CodeceptJS

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I've run into a bit of a nuisance.

I noticed that any code we add into the custom steps file isn't detected by VS Code

https://codecept.io/pageobjects/#actor

This is leading to a lot of confusion and sometimes team members removing required code due to their IDE telling them it's redundant.

We're using Javascript

```js
module.exports = function() {
  return actor({
    async myAsyncFunction(param) {
      // logic goes here
    },

    async myOtherFunction(param) {
      await this.myAsyncFunction()
    }
  });
};
```

In this example there will are 2 problems.

One, You can't deep-link back to myAsyncFunction by cmd+clicking it (MacOS)

And two, the IDE will berate you for using await on a non-promise `Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise.`

These are example from within the steps file itself, but it extends past that.

When using these functions inside of tests they also don't support intellisense and complain about using await on non-promises.

Additional note, the native CodeceptJS functions do support intellisense, this only happens for code that's new in the steps file.

The problem does not seem to exist in other IDE's. Colleagues that use Jetbrains seem to be able to use this without issues.

I've tried refactoring the code to use the same structure shown in the example [here](https://codecept.io/pageobjects/#actor)

I've also tried finding different ways to pass values back to the actor that support deep linking, but I have not managed to figure out how that works correctly yet.

I tried using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74849869/intellisense-not-working-for-playwright-rest) as well